# can't pass by reference a pointer returned from a function

Tags: c++, c++98

why I need intermediate variable to pass my return pointer by reference instead of just using the function that returns that pointer ?

This doesn't compile

```
int main ()
{
  testfunc(getpointer());
  return 0;
}
```

> error: C2664: 'void testfunc(int *&)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'int *' to 'int *&'

and this compiles

```
int main ()
{
   int *i = getpointer();
   testfunc(i);
   return 0; 
}
```

my two functions

```
void testfunc(int *& i) // I have to use this interface
{
  cout << i[0] <<endl;
}

int* getpointer()
{
  int * arr1 = new int[1];
  arr1[0]=10;
  return arr1;
}
```

Comment: Because it's a temporary object.

Comment: right ! but why this temporary object can't get passed to testfunc ? it's still has an address and it can be accessed ? right ? or do I miss something ?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz when this address get destroyed then ? I was assuming that at least the address is going to be passed to testfunc .. why not ?

Comment: @H.G Right, so what would happen to any changes `testfunc` made to it? Remember, `testfunc` takes a *non-const* reference. Fix `testfunc` to be const-correct.

Comment: In your second example you are accepting a const pointer not a const reference.

Comment: @Galik right I figured this out and it works now with testfunc(int * const & i)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The C++ language prohibits binding a non-const reference to a temporary. In this case, the simple fix is to make `testfunc` take a const reference to an `int*`.

Comment: I can't control that .. testfunc is in a 3rd party lib

Comment: @H.G Then you'll have to use some ugly hack with a copy of the temporary or a cast or something ugly like that. But understand that `testfunc` is broken.

Comment: right ! ... testfunc(int * const & i) worked fine .. unfortunate, I can't change this testfunc in my real code though .. but at least I see the problem now !

Comment: I tried it with my example and it runs fine ... do I expect random undefined behavior ?

Comment: @H.G In theory, yes. But in practice it will probably work just fine on every platform you're likely to encounter. You have a choice of horrible workarounds and, IMO, that's one of the most horrible ones.

Comment: @H.G: C++ has overloading. Just write `void testfunc(int*&& x) {testfunc(x);}`

Comment: @GManNickG works for c++11, but I'm on c++98 ... any idea ?

Comment: @H.G: Update. :) But really, nope. Take the combination of the two and make it a new function: `void dothething() { int* x = getpointer(); testfunc(x); }`.

Comment: @GManNickG :) LOL that makes sense !