# Why is const necessary here?

Tags: c++

It makes some intuitive sense why `const` is necessary here, as the number hasn't really gotten a place to land so you can't pass it by reference, but is there a more formal explanation?

```
#include <iostream>

int number()
{
    return 8;
}

int greet(const int& q)
{
    std::cout << "HI!";
    return q;
}

int main()
{
    return greet(number());
}
```

Comment: You cant bind r-values to non-const references so yes.

Comment: "Because the standard says so."

Comment: Oh right. This is an rvalue. Thank you. That made it click.

Comment: A reference for a function parameter means that you want to pass "by identity" (of an object) rather than passing a value. Temporary objects and literals don't have an identity, and therefore cannot bind to references. However, it would make it very hard to have functions that don't copy their arguments when they don't modify them, so it was relaxed to allow passing objects without identities to `const T&`

Comment: @Borgleader - non-const *lvalue* references.

Comment: The number most certainly "has a place to land". The compiler will store the temporary somewhere. But modifying it with the same function that would modify an lvalue is not a good idea. The function can't just steal data (it doesn't know *when* it's actually passed a temporary), nor can the effects of the modification on a temporary be used outside of the function. So the standard just disallowed it. Note that with an rvalue reference, you *do know* you are passed a temporary, so it's even encouraged to steal the data.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39883808/cant-pass-by-reference-a-pointer-returned-from-a-function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, you'd pass by value, since integers are cheap to copy and have value semantics.

The expression `number()` is an **rvalue** (specifically a **prvalue**), so you can't bind it with a non-const reference.  You can use an rvalue by copying it, and you're allow to bind with a const reference.

Const references are special, in that they extend the lifetime of objects, in a way that non-const references do not.  And that is the key here.